# Output Keeps Printing Vertically

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api, python-3.4

I was able to program an API call to retrieve lyrics from a public API (Specifically Awkward by Dance Gavin Dance. The thing is, when it prints, it prints the lyrics letter by letter, vertically instead pf the way it is shown on the API. This is the code:

```
import json
import requests

api_url_base = 'https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'charset': 'utf-8'}

def get_lyrics_info():

        api_url ='{0}Dance%20Gavin%20Dance/Awkward'.format(api_url_base)
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

 if response.status_code == 200:
       return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
   else:
       return None

lyric_info = get_lyrics_info()

if lyric_info is not None:
   print("Here is your info: ")
   for lyrin in lyric_info["lyrics"]:
      print(lyrin)

else:
   print('[!] Request Failed')
```

This is how the output looks like (This is just a part of the output, just to show you how it looks):

```
D
o
n
'
t

m
a
k
e

t
h
i
s

a
w
k
w
a
r
d
```

I have tried using the wrap() function, the fill() function but the variable "lyrin" is not a string. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `lyric_info["lyrics"]` a string? It would appear so, as it's iterating through each character and printing it as a new line. This could be solved by using a debugger or simply printing out the variables you're using.

Comment: It is a string from the Public API but the thing is, it doesn't appear the same way it appears on the API. Thank you for the advice, I'll use a debugger and see what comes out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for lyrin in lyric_info["lyrics"]` will iterate through all `chars`
Use `for lyrin in lyric_info["lyrics"].split('\n'):`

or do `sys.stdout.write(lyrin)`

```
import json
import requests

api_url_base = 'https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'charset': 'utf-8'}

def get_lyrics_info():
   api_url ='{0}Dance%20Gavin%20Dance/Awkward'.format(api_url_base)
   response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

   if response.status_code == 200:
       return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
   else:
      return None

lyric_info = get_lyrics_info()

if lyric_info is not None:
      print("Here is your info: ")
      for lyrin in lyric_info["lyrics"].split('\n'):
         print(lyrin)

else:
       print('[!] Request Failed')
```

or

```
import json
import requests
import sys

api_url_base = 'https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'charset': 'utf-8'}

def get_lyrics_info():
   api_url ='{0}Dance%20Gavin%20Dance/Awkward'.format(api_url_base)
   response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

   if response.status_code == 200:
       return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
   else:
      return None

lyric_info = get_lyrics_info()

if lyric_info is not None:
      print("Here is your info: ")
      for lyrin in lyric_info["lyrics"]:
         sys.stdout.write(lyrin)

else:
       print('[!] Request Failed')
```

Comment: I know this isn't the place to say it but thank you so much!

Comment: On the contrary it is pretty much the place to say it @xKMCK. Happy to help !